# salesforce - Zipped css in static resource are not rendered, why?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, staticresource

I zipped the CSS and image file so that the images are accessible by the CSS.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm

I've followed documentation code but it is not rendered at all.

```
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery_dialog_css_img,
 'jquery_ui_one_dot_eight_dot_eleven.css')}" />
```

zipped file structure is:

```
[jquery_dialog_css_img] ---- jquery_ui_one_dot_eight_dot_eleven.css
                         |
                         |---images ----- someImage.jpg
```

When the visualforce page is rendered the import tag looks like:

```
        <link class="user" href="/resource/1301916406000/
          manenabi__jquery_dialog_css_img/
          jquery_ui_one_dot_eight_dot_eleven.css" 
          rel="stylesheet" 
          type="text/css" />
```

It looks correct and I have no idea why it is not working. When I click on the generated link:

/resource/1301916406000/
              manenabi__jquery_dialog_css_img/
              jquery_ui_one_dot_eight_dot_eleven.css

The page is all blank which (I think) means somehow the path is not correct. (If is is correct, the popped up page would show the code like js or css)

Comment: I tried excluding .css extention or double it css.css but no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok... I had to include root directory.. come on doc, u didn't say that :(

I wanna shoot Salesforce with my paintball.

```
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery_dialog_css_img,
 'jquery_dialog_css_img/jquery_ui_one_dot_eight_dot_eleven.css')}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually the key here is to make sure your zip file name is the same as the resource name.

So this code:

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.name, 'style.css')}" />
```

Has to correspond to a resource called 'name' and the file uploaded to the resource also has to be exactly 'name.zip'.

Then inside name.zip, you should put the style.css file and the images directory